# Given an analytic function with $f(0) = 0$, $\Vert f'(0)\Vert= 1$, when I can I find an open invariant set?

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fractals

If $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, where $0\in\Omega$, and $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(0)| = 1$, what other conditions are necessary for finding an invariant open subset of $\Omega$? In particular, I'm wondering about this when $f''(0) = \lambda$ where $|\lambda| < 1$, when can one find a nonempty open subset $U\subset\Omega$ such that $f(U)\subset U$. It isn't necessary to know whether $0\in U$ (in fact, I doubt this is possible in general). I am wondering both

1. When does an invariant open set exist?
2. Is it possible to construct an invariant open set? (I don't care about a maximal open set here, that I assume is hard. Just any open set.)

I don't know what techniques might be applicable here. I can't even solve it for quadratic $f$. I suppose the full invariant set would be fractal, but I'm just wondering about whether I can find any open set that's invariant. If this is provably not possible to determine based on $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$, that would be interesting too.

Comment: I presume you don't want to allow the empty set.  What do you mean by "finding"?  Do you want to specify it explicitly? That seems unlikely in general if $f$ is arbitrary (and thus in general not even computable). Or do you just want it to exist?

Comment: Yes let me update

Comment: Regardless of what $f(0)$, $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ are, there might be $w$ with $f(w)=w$ and $|f'(w)| < 1$, in which case some disk around $w$ will work.  Or do you want to require $0 \in U$?

Comment: I'm interested in cases where there's no other fixed points in the domain. Mainly I'm looking for local properties around fixed points that are neither attracting nor repelling. I know this is hard in general, but I'm hoping an invariant open set isn't *too* hard.